# Adding data to textbox/label from data grid view (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

i want to know the vb.net syntax to adding data to textbox or label. for example : "I Am Soldier" where the "I Am" text is from label and "Soldier" is the data that we took from data grid view

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your TextBox already contains the string "I Am" and you are trying to add another word to it, you would [concatenate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx) the strings.

```
TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text & " " & DataGridView.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

Some people like to shorthand this using the `&=` assignment operator.

```
TextBox.Text &= " " & DataGridView.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

If your TextBox is empty you simply assign that value literally.

```
TextBox.Text = "I Am " & DataGridView.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

Comment: i got message "reference to non-shared member requires an object reference". what should i do ?? sorry i'm really newbie with this

Comment: @LukmanHakim There isn't enough information in your question to effectively help you any further with this question. Please consider reading the helpful "[ask]" article, and possibly updating your question, or asking a new question.